# Why doesn't constraintLayout's margin apply?

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I wanted to apply a margin to the bottom of the first view.

However, I found that the `bottom margin` of the above view doesn't apply.

But when I give the `top margin` to the below view it worked correctly.

Why is this?

---

This is an example pic and code.

**When bottom margin is applied to the above(test) view**

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:background="@color/light_blue_400"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/test2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray_400"
        android:text="TEST2"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/test"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**When top margin is applied to the below(test2) view**

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:background="@color/light_blue_400"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/test2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray_400"
        android:text="TEST2"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/test"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First things first**, the margin is applied only if you set a constrain in the same direction, so in the second code `android:layout_marginTop` is applied because you have `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf`.

**But** in the first code you add `layout_marginBottom` and `layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` and didn't work and hers is why?

`test2` is dependent on `test` because it does not have a constraint in the opposite direction (which is the bottom).

[image]

and because of that adding `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/test2"` to `test`, **it doesn't do anything at all**, I'm sure you hard-coded it, but if you try to do this with the design panel it not going to allow you to do this, and this is like you create **Noncomplete Chain**.

*try this code*

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@color/light_blue_400"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/test2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@color/gray_400"
        android:text="TEST2"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/test" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

then try to move the `TextViews` in the design panel, you going to notice you are not able to move the `TextViews` up or down, this is because I create a **Vertical-Chine** between `test` and `test2`.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but let me ask you a few questions.

**1.** You said "the margin is applied only if you set a constrain in the same direction". However, in my first code, the bottom direction is already constrained (`app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/test2"`). But I don't know why the margin is not applied.. The `test` already has a bottom constraint, what does it have to do with `tes2`?

Comment: **2.**
In my code, `Bottom of test` and `Top of test2` are chained. By the way, By the way, as you said, when I try to chain `test` and `tes2` in `design panel`, it doesn't chain. Constraints in only one direction. **(** from the `bottom of test` to the `top of test2`, or from the `top of test2` to the `bottom of the test` **)**. They are only chained together by hardcoding. Why?

Comment: **1** Maybe You don't finish reading, I mentioned you have a bottom margin with bottom constraint and why it didn't work, **2** to create a chain with a design panel select all views you need be chained  by **shift key+click** then **right-click** to show options, then chose chain then chose vertical-chain or horizontal-chain